# sql server restore to newer version, index best practice

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm at a site where they are upgrading a sql server (data warehouse) from 2005 to 2008. My understanding was always rebuild every index and update all your statistics after a restore from a previous version. Will it cause a big performance hit if they aren't rebuilt right away? Downtime is a concern so I'd have to schedule the rebuilds a bit at a time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you read that you should always rebuild? Update stats, yes. Update compatibility level (after testing), yes. Rebuild? I'm not sure that will always be beneficial. Also remember that on Enterprise Edition you can rebuild online.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server backups are an image of the database at the point in time the backup was performed. You do not need to rebuild indexes or update statistics, as the restored database's indexes will have the same fragmentation that they had when the backup was performed.

Comment: Although it is indeed best practice to rebuild stats because their internal format and capabilities have changed.

Comment: Im not sure how that's the case, considering that the version upgrade steps between db file versions updates the data types from the backup to their new version representation. You can verify the stats are identical after restoring, http://merlecarr.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/do-sql-server-statistics-get-updated-during-a-restoreis-this-a-myth/

Comment: I read it in a best practices document years ago and was trying to confirm. It stated something to the effect that since the optimizer has changed between versions, the old statistics aren't always useful to the new optimizer.

Comment: The old statistics will still work and indeed SQL Server does not touch them when upgrading. But why would they introduce a new format if it was good for nothing? It must have more information in it or be better in some other way. So you should manually update them to make sure you get the best performance.

Comment: There are other things like this as well. For example data purity checks that will not be performed automatically. But you can execute them manually and SQL Server will remember you did this so it can now trust the data more than before.

Comment: usr, that just doesnt pan out. Things like struct size changes and new pointers/data members would change the actual on-disk statistics data, but that very same info would be added/set as part of the db file format upgrade. If you do updatestats as the very last op before a backup, restore to a new version, and compare it to one you manually updated on the new version, the statistics would be identical.

Comment: Official documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933942%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) says that you should update statistics after an upgrade in a specific scenario (2000 -> 2008). That aside, I can think of other changes that would be made in the engine that would make you want to update them after upgrade (e.g. more histogram steps in the newer version, better heuristics for sampling, etc). Update stats is relatively cheap, and can be done online (disk contention notwithstanding). So what's the objection?

Comment: @JakeHeidt well you would execute the update *after* upgrading so that you indeed get the improved version because it is being regenerated on the new server version.; SQL Server can use both stats versions, old and new side-by-side. So that's why the restore-upgrade didn't need to change anything.